# tableView.reloadData() add new cell instead of reload the data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I try to call "reloadData" but instead of reloading the data, it adds a new cell
like this. It's a very annoying bug. Every time I come back to this page, the cell keeps increasing every time and I don't know why.

Pictured below is a bug I came across.

[image][image]

And here is my code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate =    self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourSessionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourSessionViewCellIden")
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(getSessionData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getSessionData(){
    self.yourSessionModel = []
    Firestore.firestore().collection("MSession").getDocuments(completion: { [self]
        snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error in calen firebase")
        } else {
            if !snapshot!.isEmpty {
                let ary = snapshot!.documents
                for item in ary {
                    let eventMSession = YourSessionModel(dict: item.data())
                    if(eventMSession.createdBy == AuthUser.userId()){
                        self.yourSessionModel.append(eventMSession)
                        self.users.append(YourSessionStruct(sName: eventMSession.roomName ?? "", sDes: eventMSession.subject ?? "", sCreateAt: eventMSession.createdAt ?? ""))
            
                   }
                
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

//UITableViewDataSource

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if(users.count == 0){
        return 0
    }
    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourSessionViewCellIden") as! YourSessionViewCell
    cell.sessionName.text =
    "\(users[indexPath.section].sName)"
    cell.SessionDes.text =
        " \(users[indexPath.section].sDes)"
    cell.SessionCreateAt.text =
        " \(users[indexPath.section].sCreateAt)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 220
}
```

Comment: check your timer, this the problem, you are repeating the call of the getSessionData() method each second and this method append elements to your array user, so this cause your tableview increase.

Comment: Your `getSessionData` function fetches all data from Firestore in the specified collection but it appends it to your existing `users` array.  Either replace the `users` array content each time, or probably better, get rid of the timer and use a snapshot listener so that Firestore provides changes to the collection when they happen.

Comment: One of you should post your comment as an answer, since you've identified the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate =    self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourSessionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourSessionViewCellIden")
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(getSessionData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getSessionData(){
    self.yourSessionModel = []
    self.users = [YourSessionStruct]() // Add this below self.yourSessionModel
    Firestore.firestore().collection("MSession").getDocuments(completion: { [self]
        snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error in calen firebase")
        } else {
            if !snapshot!.isEmpty {
                let ary = snapshot!.documents
                for item in ary {
                    let eventMSession = YourSessionModel(dict: item.data())
                    if(eventMSession.createdBy == AuthUser.userId()){
                        self.yourSessionModel.append(eventMSession)
                        self.users.append(YourSessionStruct(sName: eventMSession.roomName ?? "", sDes: eventMSession.subject ?? "", sCreateAt: eventMSession.createdAt ?? ""))
            
                   }
                
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

//UITableViewDataSource

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if(users.count == 0){
        return 0
    }
    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourSessionViewCellIden") as! YourSessionViewCell
    cell.sessionName.text =
    "\(users[indexPath.section].sName)"
    cell.SessionDes.text =
        " \(users[indexPath.section].sDes)"
    cell.SessionCreateAt.text =
        " \(users[indexPath.section].sCreateAt)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 220
}
```

> Adding self.users = YourSessionStruct below self.yourSessionModel
> should solve the problem.

========================================================================